# Visual studio is prompting for SQL Server Connection all the time

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012

Visual studio 2012 keeps prompting me for a SQL Server connection (repeatedly) it is very annoying.
This happens when I open my solution (even before I run it).

It is not happening my colleagues who have same solution from TFS source control.

I've tried search all files for the Server/Database shown and nothing comes back.

This is hampering my efforts to do any work.

[image]

Comment: Have you clicked the `Save my password` button when entering your password and hitting `OK`???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the similar problem. What i think you have is a stored data connection somewhere in web/app config that that is invalid which wants to connect from time to time.
From visual studio goto server explorer. Check data connections node if there is a connection that you donot need or the connection that is old. remove the data connection and that should do it. If not check for other invalid connection

Comment: Yeah it was in my app.config or web.config - can't really remember.